# Definition of friend functions and classes

Tags: c++, class, friend

Why friend functions can be defined

```
class CL
{
    friend void fnc(){}
};
```

but friend classes can't?

```
class CL
{
    friend class FriendClass{}; //error
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An inner class is a friend of the class it is declared within.

It would have no meaning to do it with a `friend` specifier since it would be an inner class with private-access to the outer one.

And, formally, the standard says:

*[class.friend]/p2*

> A class shall not be defined in a friend declaration

Comment: This approaches it but could use fleshing out.